# "Is almost a" relationships in Scala

Tags: scala, mixins

I'm trying to design a class hierarchy with a bunch of similar classes that don't quite share a "is a" relationships.  Let's call these `Model` classes.  These classes are meant to be paired with a collection similar algorithms which make use the `Model` classes but do not identically have the same requirements.  Let's call these `Strategy` classes.  The trick is that the `Strategy` classes require many of the same things from the `Model` classes, but not all `Model` classes may be able to implement those required methods.  I'd like to not have empty "stub" methods that will just throw `UnsupportedOperationException`s and instead have a type-safe mixin-based way of dealing with this -- is there a design pattern that I can apply?

For example,

```
object Main extends App {
    trait A {
        def f(one: Int): Int
        def g(two: Int): Int
        def h(three: Int): Int
    }

    class A1 extends A {
        override def f(one: Int): Int = {one + 1}
        override def g(two: Int): Int = {two + 2}
        override def h(three: Int): Int = {assert(false); 0}
    }

    class A2 extends A {
        override def f(one: Int): Int = {assert(false); 0}
        override def g(two: Int): Int = {two - 2}
        override def h(three: Int): Int = {three - 3}
    }

    trait B {
        def combine(i: Int): Int
    }

    trait B1 extends B {
        this: A =>
        override def combine(i: Int) = {f(i) + g(i)}
    }

    trait B2 extends B {
        this: A =>
        override def combine(i: Int) = {g(i) + h(i)}
    }

    override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val a11 = new A1 with B1
        val a22 = new A2 with B2

        println(a11.combine(3))
        println(a22.combine(3))

        val a12 = new A1 with B2
        println(a12.combine(3))
    }
}
```

Here `A` is a `Model` class and `B` is the `Strategy` class.  Notice that `A1` may not be able to implement `h()` and that `A2` may not be able to implement `f()`, and depending on the strategy class this may or may not be a problem.  I'd like to be able to find out which implementation of A can work with which implementation of B at compile time.

I've used [self-types](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124) to express a more "has a" than "is a" relationship that would normally go with extension.

Comment: Note your `override` modifier isn't necessary.

Comment: @PeterSchmitz I know, but I find it helps me keep track of which methods are implementing some sort of interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use structural types, the classes don't even need to be related in their hierarchy:

```
class A1 {
  def f(i: Int) = {i + 1}
  def g(i: Int) = {i + 2}
}

class A2 {
  def g(i: Int) = {i * 2}
  def h(i: Int) = {i * i}
}

type FnG = { def f(i: Int): Int; def g(i: Int): Int}

class B {
  def combine1(a: FnG, i: Int) = a.f(i) + a.g(i)
  def combine2(a: { def g(i: Int): Int; def h(i: Int): Int}, i: Int) = 
      a.g(i) + a.h(i)
}

val a1 = new A1
val a2 = new A2
val b = new B
println(b combine1(a1, 3))
println(b combine2(a2, 3))

trait C {
  def combine(i: Int): Int
}
trait C1 extends C {
  this: FnG =>
  def combine(i: Int) = f(i) + g(i)
}
trait C2 extends C {
  this: { def g(i: Int): Int; def h(i: Int): Int} =>
  def combine(i: Int) = g(i) + h(i)
}

val newA1 = new A1 with C1
val newA2 = new A2 with C2

println(newA1 combine(3))
println(newA2 combine(3))
```

This way, you only need to specify (for traits) that the base types supports specific methods, and for classses, that the passed in class supports specific methods. You don't need to assume any hierarchy.

Comment: A concise alternative, but it just screams un-maintainability.  I appreciate it all the same though!

Comment: Why unmaintainable? It seems to me to be a _looser_ fit than depending on traits. All you are specifying is that the passed in (or mixed in) object support specific operations, not that it lives on a specific class hierarchy. For example, while `insect` and `bird` may both live on the same hierarchy, `airplane` will not, but they will all support the `fly` method. Depends on you're requirements really.

Answer (score 5):

Here my solution:

```
trait F { def f(one: Int): Int }
trait G { def g(two: Int): Int }
trait H { def h(three: Int): Int }

trait A
trait A1 extends A with F with G {
  def f(one: Int): Int = { one + 1 }
  def g(two: Int): Int = { two + 2 }
}
trait A2 extends A with G with H {
  def g(two: Int): Int = { two - 2 }
  def h(three: Int): Int = { three - 3 }
}

trait B {
  def combine(i: Int): Int
}
trait B1 extends B {
  this: A with F with G =>
  def combine(i: Int) = { f(i) + g(i) }
}
trait B2 extends B {
  this: A with G with H =>
  def combine(i: Int) = { g(i) + h(i) }
}

val a11 = new A1 with B1
val a22 = new A2 with B2

println(a11.combine(3))
println(a22.combine(3))

val a12 = new A1 with B2 // won't compile as you wanted
```

Comment: Thanks!  I thought of that too, but is this really the best solution?  I feel like it's extremely verbose.  Is this the principle way things are done in the `scala.collections` library?

Comment: As far as I know things aren't composed in a `Model`-`Strategy` fashion in the collections library. There is a hierarchy and `CanBuildFrom` to ensure the "best" return type. But perhaps someone else can clarify that.